# List posts grouped by year

Tags: posts, list

I'm really stuck on this one:

Show ALL posts grouped by year

**2013**

- title1
- title2
- title3
- title4

**2012**

- title1
- title2

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Share your code what you tried.

Comment: Duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397725/wordpress-how-can-i-display-post-link-group-by-year

Comment: Please search the site, try something, then ask a question that isn't _can someone help me with this_. In it's current form the question is a (A) a duplicate and (B) just a job description and therefore highly off topic.